# how to add Controls to the custom layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

i have a custom layout called myWebView  that is extended from WebView.

```
        class myApp{
            mWebView  = new MyWebView(this);
            setContentView(mWebView);
        }  

        class MyWebView extends WebView {
            Context context;
        // codes
    }
```

I want to add textbox and  many other control to to the myWebView layout how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `mWebView.add(new TextView());` ?

Comment: Context text = null; mWebView.addView(new TextView(text)); i used this but im getting run time error..

Comment: @vnshetty try to pass YourActivity.this as a context param to the new TextView.